# ¿Como generar un descuento suma a un producto en java?

Tags: java-swing, java-8

Tengo que generar un descuento a un producto que se lo llama descuento suma, donde un producto tiene asigando varios descuentos:
Ejemplo. `precio de costo = $500 ,descuentos suma = 20+30+10+5 ,total = $239.40 la función matemática para esto es 500*(1-(20/100))*(1-(30/100))*(1-(10/100))*(1-(5/100))`
Lo que hago a continuación me devuelve lo que yo quiero siempre y cuando los valores sean 4. Ejemplo: Si tengo 20+0+0+0 funciona, pero si tengo 20+0 ya no funciona.
Como podría hacer que esta función sirva para cualquier suma que ingrese, sin importar la cantidad de descuentos que agregue.

```
    // GENERA UN DESCUENTO POR BONIFICACION`
public double descuento(double bon) {
    double bonificacion = (1 - (bon / 100));
    return bonificacion;
}

// GENERA UN AUMENTO POR FLETE U OTRO
public double formacionCosto(double f) {
    double formacionCosto = (1 + (f / 100));
    return formacionCosto;
}

// DEVUELVE LOS DESCUENTOS
public Double precioFinal() {
    double bon1 = 0;
    double bon2 = 0;
    double bon3 = 0;
    double bon4 = 0;

    double pCosto = Double.parseDouble(txtCosto.getText());
    double iva = Double.parseDouble(txtIva.getText());
    double flete = Double.parseDouble(txtFlete.getText());
    double gan = Double.parseDouble(txtGanancia.getText());
    double pVenta = 0;

    String descuento = txtDescuentos.getText();
    String[] descuentos = descuento.split("\\+");// OBTENGO LOS NUMEROS SEPARADOS
    int numBon = descuentos.length; // OBTENGO LA CANTIDAD DE BONIFICACIONES
    if (numBon < 4) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe completar con 0 hasta el 4to descuento");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
            bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
            bon2 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[1]);
            bon3 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[2]);
            bon4 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[3]);
        }
        pVenta = pCosto * descuento(bon1) * descuento(bon2) + descuento(bon3) *descuento(bon4)
                * formacionCosto(flete) * formacionCosto(iva) * formacionCosto(gan);

    }
    return pVenta;
}
```

Comment: Pude resolver este problema de la siguiente manera.

Comment: La respuesta va en el campo Tu Respuesta, abajo. :)

Comment: No veo ese campo xD que indicas! pòr eso edite la pregunta

Comment: Debajo de estos comentarios verás una caja de texto titulada **Tu Respuesta**. Es para... tu respuesta!

Comment: @Alfabravo GRACIAS! ahi lo corregí

Answer (score 0):

//SOLUCION PLANTEADA

Utilice varios ciclos for para cada una de las opciones, por el momento deberia indicar que si supera el maximo de 4 envie un msj al usuario para añadir nueva bonificacion.

```
public interface Utilidades {

// GENERA UN DESCUENTO POR BONIFICACION
public static double descuento(double bon) {
    double bonificacion = (1 - (bon / 100));
    return bonificacion;
}

// GENERA UN AUMENTO POR FLETE U OTRO
public static double formacionCosto(double f) {
    double formacionCosto = (1 + (f / 100));
    return formacionCosto;
}
    // DEVUELVE costo
    public static Double costo(JTextField plista, JTextField bonificaciones) {
        double bon1 = 0;
        double bon2 = 0;
        double bon3 = 0;
        double bon4 = 0;
        double pCosto = 0;
        double pLista = Double.parseDouble(plista.getText());
        double pVenta = 0;

        String descuento = bonificaciones.getText();

        String[] descuentos = descuento.split("\\+");// OBTENGO LOS NUMEROS SEPARADOS
        int numBon = descuentos.length; // OBTENGO LA CANTIDAD DE BONIFICACIONES
        if (numBon == 1) {// PRIMER BONIFICACION

            for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);

            }
            pCosto = pLista * descuento(bon1);
        } else if (numBon == 2) {// SEGUNDA BONIFICACION

            for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
                bon2 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[1]);

            }

            pCosto = pLista * descuento(bon1) * descuento(bon2);

        } else if (numBon == 3) {// TERCER BONIFICACION

            for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
                bon2 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[1]);
                bon3 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[2]);
            }
            pCosto = pLista * descuento(bon1) * descuento(bon2) * descuento(bon3);

        } else {// CUARTA BONIFICACION
            for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
                bon2 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[1]);
                bon3 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[2]);
                bon4 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[3]);
            }
            pCosto = pLista * descuento(bon1) * descuento(bon2) * descuento(bon3);

        }

        return pCosto;
    }
    
    // DEVUELVE PRECIO DE VENTA
    public static Double precioVenta(JTextField txtCosto,JTextField txtDescuento,JTextField txtIva,JTextField Flete,JTextField ganancia) {
        double bon1 = 0;
        double bon2 = 0;
        double bon3 = 0;
        double bon4 = 0;
         
        double pCosto = Double.parseDouble(txtCosto.getText());
        double iva = Double.parseDouble(txtIva.getText());
        double flete = Double.parseDouble(Flete.getText());
        double gan = Double.parseDouble(ganancia.getText());
        double pVenta = 0;

        String descuento = txtDescuento.getText();
        String[] descuentos = descuento.split("\\+");// OBTENGO LOS NUMEROS SEPARADOS
        int numBon = descuentos.length; // OBTENGO LA CANTIDAD DE BONIFICACIONES
        if (numBon == 1) {//PRIMER BONIFICACION
            
                for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
                
            }
            pVenta = pCosto * descuento(bon1) * formacionCosto(flete) 
                    * formacionCosto(iva) * formacionCosto(gan);
            }else if(numBon == 2) {//SEGUNDA BONIFICACION
                
                for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                    bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
                    bon2 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[1]);
                
            }
                pVenta = pCosto * descuento(bon1) * descuento(bon2) 
                            * formacionCosto(flete) * formacionCosto(iva) * formacionCosto(gan);
        } else if(numBon==3) {//TERCER BONIFICACION
            for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
                bon2 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[1]);
                bon3 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[2]);
            }
            pVenta = pCosto * descuento(bon1) * descuento(bon2) * descuento(bon3) 
                        * formacionCosto(flete) * formacionCosto(iva) * formacionCosto(gan);
            }else {//CUARTA BONIFICACION
                for (int i = 0; i < numBon; i++) {
                    bon1 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[0]);
                    bon2 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[1]);
                    bon3 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[2]);
                    bon4 = Double.parseDouble(descuentos[3]);
                }
                pVenta = pCosto * descuento(bon1) * descuento(bon2) * descuento(bon3) * descuento(bon4)
                * formacionCosto(flete) * formacionCosto(iva) * formacionCosto(gan);
            }
            

        
        return pVenta;
    }
```

}